# A simple way to remove newlines (line breaks) between CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, html-email

With gulp-beautify I'm optimizing files containing CSS for email, which means they can't have newlines between selectors, since there is a limit on the total number of lines allowed in some email clients. I've found Beautify has an option to *add* newlines between selectors, but it doesn't have a feature to *remove* them. If selector_separator_newline is false, it ignores newlines if present.

I'm building tasks for two outputs, minified, and beautified. Obviously, the minified version doesn't need this.

I could minify before I beautify, but that removes comments, and I need to preserve comments.

I could remove all new lines and then run Beautify, and I'm looking into doing that, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Is there a package, out-of-the-box, or otherwise simple way to remove all newlines / line breaks between selectors?

Comment: Maybe try prettier

Comment: I arrived at Beautify after finding Prettier did not have options for what I was trying to do. Is there a feature for this I missed?

Comment: Sorry was on my phone. You're right I can't find a setting for either that lets you do that, weird

Comment: If you're looking at HTML email, check out https://htmlcrush.com/light - looks like it's all JavaScript so can see the code. Furthermore, note that you should not remove all spacing between curly braces/accolades due to this bug https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/92